# Create additional columns based on factor names in one column

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am looking to create additional columns in R from one original factor column (that contains a raw output file name).

Here is an example:
Original:

```
FileName <- c("123456_D1_5k", "123456_D1_10k", "123456_D2_5k", "123456_D2_10k",
              "987654_D1_5k", "987654_D1_10k", "987654_D2_5k", "987654_D2_10k")

Value <- c("5", "9", "14", "15",
           "14", "21", "24", "16")

df <- data.frame(FileName, Value)
```

Desired Output:

```
Name <- c("123456", "123456", "123456", "123456",
              "987654", "987654", "987654", "987654")

Day <- c("D1", "D1", "D2", "D2",
         "D1", "D1", "D2", "D2")

Density <- c("5k", "10k","5k", "10k",
             "5k", "10k","5k", "10k")

Value <- c("5", "9", "14", "15",
           "14", "21", "24", "16")

df_new <- data.frame(Name, Day, Density, Value)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Tried duplicating the original column multiple times and then removing text in each newly created column to get the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr) #version >= 1.3.0
separate_wider_delim(df, FileName, delim = "_",
    names = c("Name", "Day", "Density"))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 8 × 4
  Name   Day   Density Value
  <chr>  <chr> <chr>   <chr>
1 123456 D1    5k      5    
2 123456 D1    10k     9    
3 123456 D2    5k      14   
4 123456 D2    10k     15   
5 987654 D1    5k      14   
6 987654 D1    10k     21   
7 987654 D2    5k      24   
8 987654 D2    10k     16
```

---

Or in `base R` with `read.table`

```
cbind(read.table(text = df$FileName, sep = "_", header = FALSE, 
   col.names = c("Name", "Day", "Density")), df['Value'])
    Name Day Density Value
1 123456  D1      5k     5
2 123456  D1     10k     9
3 123456  D2      5k    14
4 123456  D2     10k    15
5 987654  D1      5k    14
6 987654  D1     10k    21
7 987654  D2      5k    24
8 987654  D2     10k    16
```

Answer (score 1):

## base R

```r
strcapture("(.*)_(.*)_(.*)", df$FileName, list(Name="", Day="", Density="")) |>
  cbind(df[,"Value",drop=FALSE])
#     Name Day Density Value
# 1 123456  D1      5k     5
# 2 123456  D1     10k     9
# 3 123456  D2      5k    14
# 4 123456  D2     10k    15
# 5 987654  D1      5k    14
# 6 987654  D1     10k    21
# 7 987654  D2      5k    24
# 8 987654  D2     10k    16
```

## tidyr

```r
library(dplyr) # not _strictly_ required ...
library(tidyr) # separate
df %>%
  separate(FileName, into = c("Name", "Day", "Density"))
#     Name Day Density Value
# 1 123456  D1      5k     5
# 2 123456  D1     10k     9
# 3 123456  D2      5k    14
# 4 123456  D2     10k    15
# 5 987654  D1      5k    14
# 6 987654  D1     10k    21
# 7 987654  D2      5k    24
# 8 987654  D2     10k    16
```